# How can I predict which implementation will be chosen when mixing in multiple traits with conflicting abstract overrides?

Tags: scala, mixins, traits, subtyping

Consider this example:

```
abstract class Writer {
  def write(message: String): Unit
}

trait UpperCaseFilter extends Writer {
  abstract override def write(message: String) =
    super.write(message.toUpperCase)
}

trait LowerCaseFilter extends Writer {
  abstract override def write(message: String) =
    super.write(message.toLowerCase)
}

class StringWriter extends Writer {
  val sb = new StringBuilder

  override def write(message: String) =
    sb.append(message)

  override def toString = sb.toString
}

object Main extends App {
  val writer = new StringWriter with UpperCaseFilter with LowerCaseFilter
  writer.write("Hello, world!")
  println(writer)
}
```

I was surprised by the output “HELLO, WORLD!” Why is the output not “hello, world!” or a compilation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic that decides it is called **linearization**. You can find more information about it here:

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.6

In your case the whole class hierarchy would linearized like this:

`LowerCaseFilter` > `UpperCaseFilter` > `Writer` > `StringWriter` > `AnyRef` > `Any`

So, as you can see, `UpperCaseFilter` was the last transformation that went to the `StringWriter`.

Comment: Why is it `UpperCaseFilter` > `Writer` > `StringWriter` and not `UpperCaseFilter` > `StringWriter`? Or likewise, why is it `LowerCaseFilter` > `UpperCaseFilter` and not `LowerCaseFilter` > `Writer` > `UpperCaseFilter`? And how can `Writer.write` be called at all? It’s abstract.

Comment: You can look at the link I mentioned in the answer. It describes the process of linearization in detail and gives an example with step-by-step linearization of class hierarchy.

Comment: sorry, I mean that `LowerCaseFilter` > `UpperCaseFilter` > `Writer` > `StringWriter` > `AnyRef` > `Any` is just an order of the types. An abstract method would not be called of course